# Refresh after postback causes the same data to be sent again

Tags: c#, asp.net, refresh, postback, page-refresh

I have a form to edit employee information.  If the user wishes to enter a new e-mail address for the selected employee, there is a textbox and a button that says "Add Email Address."  Very simple, you enter the e-mail address, click Add Email Address.  It postsback and that button's event handler executes the INSERT to the database.

---

**The problem:**
If you press F5 to refresh the page after that postback, it causes the same postback to occur, even if the textbox is blank.  In other words, for every time you hit F5, the actions in the event handler for that Add Email Address button occur again.  If I hit F5 ten times, the same e-mail address shows up in the database ten times.

---

One suggestion I found said, "just re-direct to the same page after you apply your changes."  The reason this is not ideal in our case is that it's a rather lengthy form of employee data --- if the user makes a bunch of changes to the overall form (such as FirstName, LastName, etc.), then makes an e-mail addition before applying the changes elsewhere, those changes elsewhere would be lost if we re-directed to the same page.

The very long winded solution I can think of is, capture all of the data in ViewState, carry it across the re-direct to the same page, then use a query string in the URL to determine if we want to fill in the data from ViewState.  Before I embark on that path, I'm hoping that instead of that, there is some method I just don't know that says like, PostbackButDontRetainPostbackData() (wishful thinking, I know).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the handler for that Add Email Address button check if the email already exists in the database. If it does, do not add the email again and display an appropriate message to the user. Usually forms have a reserved area like a hidden div for this purpose so in case anything goes wrong the div will be populated with error messages and displayed to the user.

Also, it would help to display a confirmation message to the user when their data is successfully received and processed.

**UPDATE**

If you don't like to show any messages to the user, simply do nothing after you find out that the email already exists in the database. e.g.:

```
public void AddEmailToDB(string email)
{
    // first find out if the email already exists in the database
    bool isDuplicate = ...; 
    // if it does, simply return and do nothing
    if(isDuplicate) return; 

    // if control reaches here then the email is not
    // a duplicate and you can do your normal processing
}
```

**UPDATE II**

If you don't want the browsers to show a messagebox everytime a user presses F5 after a postback, you can do a partial postback using AJAX by wrapping your email textbox and add button in an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx), it's very easy to use.

Comment: I see what you're saying, and indeed we will be checking if the e-mail address exists.  That will still result in an irrelevant message box for every refresh.  What I want is the page refresh to refresh the page without the previous postback'd data.

Comment: @CptSupermrkt, are you are referring to the messagebox shown by browsers?